# How to read filename, strip out the name and others, create a folder and move the file to it folder with nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I will like some assistant on this.

i want to create a script that will read/watch a folder.

pull out the filename

move the file to its folder and organize it properly.

**Example:**

**i have files in this order**

../downloads/in.the.moment.s01e05.480p.mkv

../downloads/in.the.moment.s01e04.480p/in.the.moment.s01e04.480p.mkv

../downloads/boma.s04e04.mkv

../downloads/boma.s04e06/boma.s04e06.mkv

../downloads/things.falls.out.1080p/things.falls.out.1080p.mkv

**and i want it to move and arrange the like this.**

../series/in.the.moment/s01/in.the.moment.s01e04.480p.mkv

../series/in.the.moment/s01/in.the.moment.s01e05.480p.mkv

../series/boma/s04/boma.s04e04.mkv

../series/boma/s04/boma.s04e06.mkv

../movies/things.falls.out.1080p.mkv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well reading and writing files is pretty easy; you can learn how to do that on your own. As for creating a new route based on what you have there, you can just map over the files one by one like so:

```
function mapToNewPath(filename) {
  // this regexp strips out different parts of the filename
  // first capture group is for series name
  // second capture group is for the season
  // only matches series episodes
  var matches = filename.match(/^(.*?)\.(s[0-9]*)e[0-9]*/);

  var series = matches && matches[1];
  var season = matches && matches[2];

  if (series) {
    return 'series/' + series + '/' + season + '/' + filename;
  }

  return 'movies/' + filename;
}
```